# Higher order TypeScript functions

Tags: typescript, higher-order-functions

I have an opposite kind of question - why does this work?

Using a first order base function `r`, and two higher order functions `f` and `g` that modifies the output shape of a function with the same signature as `r`, how come that composition like what is done below doesn't trigger an error? After all, the output the new function provided by `f(r)` has a different shape.

```
type TRSignature = (i1: string, i2: string) => { o1: string, o2: string }
const r: TRSignature = (i1, i2) => ({ o1: `foo: ${i1}`, o2: `bar: ${i2}` })

type TFSignature = (rIn: TRSignature) =>
  (...args: Parameters<TRSignature>) => ReturnType<TRSignature> & { o3: string }
const f: TFSignature = rIn => (i1, i2) => ({...rIn(i1, i2), o3: '(through f)' })

type TGSignature = (rIn: TRSignature) =>
  (...args: Parameters<TRSignature>) => ReturnType<TRSignature> & { o4: string }
const g: TGSignature = rIn => (i1, i2) => ({...rIn(i1, i2), o4: '(through g)' })

console.log(g(f(r))('hello', 'there'))
```

Output:

```
{
  o1: 'foo: hello',
  o2: 'bar: there',
  o3: '(through f)',
  o4: '(through g)'
}
```

Bonus question: are `f` and `g` functors?

Comment: How do they have a different shape? It'd be easier if you could explain your thinking behind this.

Comment: `f` adds the property `o3`, so the input to `g` is a function with a different signature (the output contains the property `o3` not specified in `TRSignature`).

Comment: does this help you ?[function-parameter-bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) and [comparing-two-functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions)

Comment: This isn't a matter of parameter bivariance (the functions have the same parameters, just different return types), and it isn't an unsound behaviour. Simply put, it's because `f(r)`'s return type is assignable to `r`'s return type, and therefore `f(r)` is assignable to `TRSignature`. So, it's a matter of return type covariance.

Comment: Nice question, see also: `const output = g(f(r))('hello', 'there');
output.o3 <-- error here Property 'o3' does not exist on type '{ o1: string; o2: string; } & { o4: string; }'
`

Comment: @kaya3 You are right. I should refer to [comparing-two-functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) ;
> The type system enforces that the source function’s return type be a subtype of the target type’s return type.